# Alignment issue in the chat site's site switcher

Tags: bug, design, chat, stack-exchange-button

There is an alignment issue in the chat site's site switcher.
"Find a Stack Exchange community" text is overlapped with the Search icon.

For example : Site switcher in the following chat sites

- https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

> [image: Search icon issue]

**Configuration:**
Operating System: Windows 10
Zoom: 100%
Mozila Firefox : 80.0.1 (64-bit)
Google Chrome : Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 80.0.1

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome ver. 85.0.4183.102 (64 bit).

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Firefox version 82.0 (64-bit).